# Getting discord.py bot to run when prompted on a flask app

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am building a discord bot on top of a flask framework, and what I am trying to do is make the bot say a message in a channel when a button is clicked on the flask web page. When I try to run my code, I get

```
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

Here is all my code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from flask import Flask,render_template,redirect
from threading import Thread
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

async def send_message():
    channel = client.get_channel('channel_id')
    await channel.send(f"This is a test")

@app.route("/send-message")
def send():
    asyncio.run(send_message())
    return redirect("/")

apiKey = "bot_token"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Thread(target=app.run,kwargs={"host": "localhost"}).start()
    client.run(apiKey)
```

Please help.